# SMS sent to Twilio aren't received according to logs

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm currently working as a programmer analyst in a company and we built an app that send invites to an event by SMS with the help of the `Twilio` API.

Here's how it works:
When a new event is created, a phone number is reserved on Twilio through the API. Then, when people are invited in the app, a SMS is sent from the reserved phone number, here again through the API. People who get the SMS can answer to the SMS by “Yes” or “No”. Our app handles the answer of the person to see if he/she will be present or not at the event.

Most of the time, everything works. The phone number is reserved properly, the invites are sent to people, and answers are handled as expected.

But since few days, we're having some issues where answers to invites aren’t received in the app.

Here’s our investigation for now:

1. An event is successfully created in our app and phone number is reserved properly in Twilio.
2. Invites are sent properly to people by SMS.
3. `Twilio` logs are showing outbound SMS.
4. Invites are properly received by people.
5. When they answer to the invite, nothing occurs. Nothing is available in Twilio logs.
6. If I try to text an existing phone number of an event that is working, I can see the SMS in Twilio logs.
7. We checked, the problem is present with different carriers.

In summary, some of the phone numbers used aren’t receiving answers by SMS, while there isn't any problem with others.

We opened a ticket with the `Twilio` support and are currently investigating with them and I contacted the carrier of the cellphones used for testing, but I still want to ask you guys, in case anyone had a similar issue and could help.

Comment: In item 5. Is this a US number? Is the size of the text < 160 chars? Is this happening to only newly reserved numbers? Any pattern in how often this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.

Use Case: Xfinity is setup for two-factor. Would like for 2-factor authentication to go to a Twilio number which will forward to myself and wife. When Xfinity sends the validation sms message it does not show up in the log or to the forwarded number. Sending messages from another mobile device works fine.

I use TwiML Bin for this. Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message to="+1xxxxxxxxxx">{{From}}: {{Body}}</Message>
</Response>
```